# Can't get averages aligned properly

Tags: java, formatting

More hw issues :D I need to have the averages aligned. I tried, but the student names are different lengths and using `printf` works to an extent but for names longer than others they are not lined up. I don't know how to get them to be lined up

```
System.out.println("You Chose Student Average\n");
                int avg;

                while(inFile.hasNext())
                {
                    name = inFile.next();
                    test1 = inFile.nextInt();
                    test2 = inFile.nextInt();

                    avg = (test1 + test2)/2;

                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.printf("%14d\n", avg);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
```

And then here is the averages output:

```
Robert            76
Joel            57
Alice            96
Jasmine            84
Larry            55
Elizabeth            82
Frank            70
Christine            28
Alex            26
Ariel            82
Luis            71
Nicole            64
Mitch            92
Randy            87
Tammy            87
Sarah            74
Samuel            73
Lauren            59
Deanna            98
Mathew            93
Justin            72
Beth            95
Rebecca            84
Paul            54
Lucy            45
```

What do?

Comment: we will not do your homework for you

Comment: Not asking to do it for me but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: @user2297156 I've given answer below. Also when you ask a question, don't just go off, wait for at least 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String formatting for more than just integers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

However, unless you have a specifically defined maximum name length I think the best you can do is check for maximum name length, then add spaces to all other names until they match that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "\t". Like:

```
System.out.println("Name: \t" + average);
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using `printf` try:

```
System.out.printf("%14d \t \n", avg);
```